# How to anchor line start and end point to ImageView on Android?

Tags: android

I have two `ImageView`s (1, 2) and I need to connect them to each other by line (`Path` class I think), when moving `ImageView` from position 1 to 3 line must dynamically change and be anchored to `ImageView`s

[image]

Comment: so draw the `Path` using `Canvas#drawPath`, whats the problem?

Comment: There is no problem with drawing the `Path`. Problem is to attach line start and end point to `imageView` and move `imageView` whith the line.

Comment: yo know the x,y positions of your `ImageView`s, right? so i dont understand you problem actually

Comment: Yes, i have those x,y. I dont understand how to attach `imageView` to line and then move it together. I know how to move `imageView` across the screen but  not together with line.

Comment: what is the parent view of your 3 ImageViews? is it a FrameLayout, RelativeLayout or something else? then make it a custom one and override its `draw` / `dispatchDraw` method

Comment: Its a RelativeLayout. I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it like this :

I use custom `PaintView` that extends `SurfaceView`. In this class you must extend methods like `touchMove`, `touchStart`, `touchUp`. You must have some initial variables as start point that will be connected to last point when you call method `touchUp`and you must have Canvas class that holds the "draw" calls. In this case it is connected in touchUp method where you are drawing line from first `initX` and `initY` points to last point in your array of X and Y coordinates or path.

```
public class PaintView extends SurfaceView
{
    protected boolean changed = false;
    protected View layout;
    protected int progress;
    private PaintView pv;
    protected float stroke = 6.0F;
    private Paint bmpPaint;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private int colour;
    private Context context;
    private float mX;
    private float mY;
    private float initX;
    private float initY;
    private ArrayList<Float> xCoords;
    private ArrayList<Float> yCoords;

    private void touchMove(float paramFloat1, float paramFloat2)
    {
        float f1 = Math.abs(paramFloat1 - this.mX);
        float f2 = Math.abs(paramFloat2 - this.mY);
        if ((f1 >= 1.8F) || (f2 >= 1.8F))
        {
            this.path.quadTo(this.mX, this.mY, (paramFloat1 + this.mX) / 2.0F, (paramFloat2 + this.mY) / 2.0F);
            this.mX = paramFloat1;
            this.mY = paramFloat2;

            xCoords.add(paramFloat1);
            yCoords.add(paramFloat2);
        }
    }

    private void touchStart(float paramFloat1, float paramFloat2)
    {
        this.clear();
        this.path.moveTo(paramFloat1, paramFloat2);
        this.mX = paramFloat1;
        this.mY = paramFloat2;
        this.initX = paramFloat1;
        this.initY = paramFloat2;
        xCoords.add(paramFloat1);
        yCoords.add(paramFloat2);
    }

    private void touchUp()
    {
        this.path.lineTo(this.initX, this.initY);
        this.canvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);            
        this.clear();
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        this.path.reset();
        this.canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        if (this.bgImage != null) {
            this.canvas.drawBitmap(this.bgImage, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getXCoords(){
        return xCoords;
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getYCoords(){
        return yCoords;
    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas paramCanvas)
    {
        paramCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paramCanvas.drawBitmap(this.bgImage, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);
        paramCanvas.drawBitmap(this.bmp, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);
        paramCanvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);
    }
}
```

It will eventually look like this :

[image: draw]